# deserialize json to general object (without predefined schema)

Tags: json, string, json.net, deserialization, .net-4.5

I'm trying to use json.net.

I'd like to get a string (in json format) and convert it to general json object, without predefined schema.

somelting like

```
 var jsonString = @"{\""id\"": 1,\""name\"": \""A green door\""}";    
 var jsonMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonString);    
 var myValue = jsonMessage["name"]
```

Is that something doable? didn't make it work

Comment: Can you show the JSON you're working with? Why didn't what you tried work?

Comment: edited the example above...got :{"Invalid property identifier character: \\. Path '', line 1, position 1."}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is malformed, try this string instead:

```
var jsonString = "{\"id\": 1,\"name\": \"A green door\"}";
```

You could also shorten this a little bit:

```
string name = JObject.Parse(jsonString)["name"].ToObject<string>();
```

Comment: Or `@"{""id"": 1,""name"": ""A green door""}"`, if you want to keep the verbatim string.